# I want to add ssl certificate in python code but i don't know how to add it in the code

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I had an ssl certificate but i don't know how to add the ssl certificate. This is what i tried:

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='0.0.0.0', user='root', password='password',ssl ={ 'cert':'client-cert.pem','key': 'client-key.pem','ca':'server-ca.pem'} )
```

This is the error:

```
certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for '0.0.0.0'. (_ssl.c:1051))"
```

Comment: Where's the mySQL server running? Try specifying localhost or 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0? Could be that the ssl cert is freaking out on the general ip connect? I don't THINK that's it, but something to eliminate.

Comment: `host=0.0.0.0` is not a valid TCP/IP address to connect to. This address has a special meaning which is "listen on all available networks" and is used for server side "listens". You will need to specify that actual TCP/IP address of the host that you want to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

cert=C:\Users\selva\SSL\loca.crt

i think you can specify the path and pass this as parameter.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration

Comment: i tried with that too by adding the specified path. Still having the same error.